# Handling Nonetype for setting a path

Tags: python, dry

I have the following piece of code in which I have been thinking on how to write it more concisely. In the lines bellow I have a variable called `export_path` which may be given by the user or not, and in case it is given, the generated file will be exported to that folder. However, in case it is `None`, then the files are exported to the CWD.

```
if export_path is not None:
    export_directory = export_path + f'/{project_name}'
    with open(export_directory, 'w') as file:
        file.write(text)
else:
    with open(f'{project_name}', 'w') as file:
        file.write(text)
```

My problem is, I would like to avoid this if/else block and make it cleaner. My main struggle so far is regarding on how to deal with the variable `export_path` when it is none. Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
export_directory = export_path + f'/{project_name}'
with open(export_directory, 'w') as file:
     file.write(text)
```

And in case `export_path` is `None`, then would only export to the CWD. But, the problem here is that obviously you cannot sum a Nonetype and a string. So here it comes my question, it somehow to handle this `Nonetype` in such a way that it would make it possible to create a one-liner path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
exp_directory = export_path if export_path is not None else f"{project_name}"
```

Comment: or `f"{project_name}" if export_path is None else export_path` (avoids a negation - positive assertions usually require less cognitive charge).

Comment: Whatever floats your boat @brunodesthuilliers! I prefer my way since it reads more like a sentence to me